# formula field to calculate override field

Tags: salesforce, overriding

Trying to create a formula field so it checks if there is an override field (currency), if there isn't an override field, it should calculate the value based on two other fields (i.e. contract length and monthly rev).

what am i missing in this below formula

BLANKVALUE(ACV_Override__c, Monthly_Revenue__c * MIN( Contract_Length__c ,12))

it is accepting the formula but when i look at the opportunity reports, the formula field only picks up the over ride amount (when there is one) , if not, then it leaves it blank instead of calculating the 'Monthly_Revenue__c * MIN( Contract_Length__c ,12'

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the ACV_Override__c field is blank? Perhaps there is a default value on it?

Can you try this otherwise ?

IF( ISBLANK( ACV_Override__c)  || (ACV_Override__c == 0) , Monthly_Revenue__c * MIN( Contract_Length__c ,12), ACV_Override__c))

Comment: the ACV override field is actually blank - strangely my formula did not work, but what you suggested above now works! thanks a lot